# HTML superscript shows Â character

Tags: html, superscript

I have the following `11,500m<sup>²</sup>` in my HTML code. The superscript 2 displays fine, but adds an extra character out of nowhere, like so:

11,500mÂ²

Does anyone know what is causing this and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following inside < HEAD > tag

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

example

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
   ..
 </head>
 <body>
  ..
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that using the superscript 2 (`²`) instead of a _normal_ `2` might have rendering issues with some fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the character for the number `2` (and not for the [superscripted 2](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b2/index.htm)).

```
11,500m<sup>2</sup>
```

11,500m<sup>2</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with ®, it is by nature hovering on the top half. I used the number representation `&#174;` that solves the problem.